# pyshark - data from TCP packet

Tags: python, wireshark, packet-capture, pyshark

Is there anyway to get the payload of a TCP packet using pyshark?

I am trying to compare the data sections of different packets across multiple TCP streams but I can't find a way to get at the data of the packet. `pkt['tcp'].data` does not seem to exist.

Comment: have you tried [this](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark#accessing-packet-data)?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this problem. Even I am facing the same problem!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a .pcap file, once you have read the file using

```
cap = pyshark.FileCapture('vox.pcap')
```

and say, you want to read the data of the 2nd packet, and you are sure such a field exists, try:

```
pkt = cap[1]
print pkt.tcp.data
```

To see the options available for pkt.tcp, use:

```
dir(pkt.tcp)
```

It will return all the available options for pkt.tcp

Comment: I am getting exception when I try data and dir(cap[x].tcp) does not have 'data' in it!

Answer (score 3):

Using pyshark 0.3.7.11 with python 3.6 and
Assuming you have loaded a capture file, you can get the tcp payload with:

```
p = capfile[0] # or any packet you know has a tcp layer
payload = p.tcp.payload
```

> p.tcp.payload Out[139]:
>   '6f:00:2c:00:01:00:02:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02:00:00:00:00:00:b2:00:1c:00:81:00:00:00:01:00:03:00:03:00:02:00:00:00:00:00:64:00:01:00:04:00:02:00:6b:00:03:00

You can find out the fields you can access with the following:

```
dir(p) # for entire packet
dir(p.ip) # for ip layer
dir(p.tcp) # for tcp layer
```

Print out information in a nice pretty format:

```
print(p.tcp)  # one way
p.tcp.pretty_print() # using pretty print
```

Not sure what else might be useful to you.
Docs are at https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
import pyshark
import sys

cap = pyshark.FileCapture(sys.argv[-1])
for i in cap:
    try:
        print(i.data.data)
    except:
        print("no data")
```